# How to have border of different sizes in wxwidgets?

Tags: alignment, wxpython, wxwidgets

Usually when we add a particular widget to a sizer in wxwidgets we specify alignment and border flags as ( .... ,wxALIGN_RIGH | wxLEFT | wxRIGHT , 10 )

My requirement is I would like to have left border of 10 and right border of 20 , how do I achieve this with flag combination or is a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it the way that you want to.
You would have to omit wx.RIGHT from your command and add an extra dummy widget to the box:

```
   hbox.Add((dummy,-1, wx.LEFT,20))
```

If attempting to do it in a vertical box:

```
   vbox.Add((-1, 20))
```

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# border.py

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(260, 180))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        midPan = wx.Panel(panel)
        midPan.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')
        dummy = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        midPan2 = wx.Panel(panel)
        midPan2.SetBackgroundColour('#1f1f1f')

        hbox.Add(midPan, -1, wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10 )
        hbox.Add(dummy,-1, wx.LEFT,border=20)
        hbox.Add(midPan2, -1, wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        vbox.Add(hbox)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Border')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful